# JAXBElement<T> make the declared type T as a parameter to work with any class

Tags: java, jaxb, classname

I got this code

```
private Object fooMethod(Node node, Class classOut)
  JAXBElement<MessageAcknowledgementType> root = unmarshallerjaxObject.unmarshal(node, MessageAcknowledgementType.class);
```

Since I am going to call the fooMethod with different class names, I want to specify into the JAXBElement the name of the class from the variable classOut, I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
JAXBElement <classOut.getSimpleName()> root = unmarshallerjaxObject.unmarshal(node, classOut.getSimpleName()); //It doesn't work
```

Any idea about how to specify the class name into the JAXBElement?. Thank you!.

Comment: What does do `fooMethod(Class)`?

Comment: fooMethod(Class) is doing an unmarshalling to an object

Comment: I'm still having difficulties understanding what does it do. Is it possible publishing some code without exposing trade secrets?

Comment: Hi Boris, no problem, I added more code, and now I hope it's clear what I want to do. I just want the unmarshaling to work with any different class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing is:

```
private Object fooMethod(Node node, Class<?> classOut) {
    JAXBElement<?> root = unmarshallerjaxObject.unmarshal(node, classOut);
}
```

Comment: That was a really elegant solution, I knew there had to be a simple way to do it, thanks Tom!.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
Object obj = fooMethod(node, classout);
```

Define another method which will cast it to the appropriate type for you:

```
private <T> JAXBElement<T> getCast(Class<T> clazz, Object obj){
    return (JAXBElement<T>)obj;
}

     JAXBElement<Member> jaxbElement = getCast(SomeClass.class, obj);
```

Comment: Hi Biju, thanks a lot for your answer. I don't think I can change the return type of the method because it's been use by other people. I have added more code that maybe helps to understand my question. Thank you

Comment: He means to call the new method from your existing method.